# my $ajax call is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

When executing the following code:

```
url= "http://192.168.2.171/LoginAuthentication";
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var headline = $(res.responseText).find('a.tsh').text();
        alert(headline);
    }
});
```

I get this error:

```
Object XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'url'. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: Just google for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and the reason should become clear.

Comment: it must be `url: url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers do not allow you to request resources from another domain (images and script files are the notable exceptions to this rule). Refer to [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) for details and workarounds.

Comment: $.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType : "jsonp",
  url : "http://192.168.2.171/LoginAuthentication",
  success : parsexml,
  xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
 });

Comment: If the resource you request supports [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), you can use that. Otherwise, you have to get a CORS policy deployed. One way or the other, you need collaboration from the remote domain administration.

Answer (score 0):

```
url="http://192.168.2.171/LoginAuthentication";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var headline = $(res.responseText).find('a.tsh').text();
        alert(headline);
    }
});
```

But it may not work if you are not making a request to the same domain

Comment: That does not fix the problem (as you noted yourself). I corrected the JavaScript syntax in the question, though.

Comment: @AdrianLang The typo could be in the real code and be a part of the issue. I think it's better leave this kind of update to OP

Comment: Well, it's a problem, and probably a real one, but not part of the main issue.